# Why is my question getting downvoted?

Tags: support, down-votes

For some reason [my question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237384/what-is-the-difference-between-the-stealth-tank-in-xxx-state-of-the-union-and-b) had a struggle, because it got a downvote. Later, I updated the question by doing a comparison, but that just made it worse and it got another downvote without any explanations. I got so upset of how I reacted to those users downvoting my question.

Can somebody help me how to update that question correctly so it gets upvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several people didn't understand your question, as evidenced by the comments and comment upvotes

> I don't understand your question. What would it mean for one fictional tank to "be" another fictional tank?

I would imagine that both of the people who upvoted that comment also downvoted your question so it's not true that these downvotes are happening '*without explanation'*.

---

<s>As to whether it will *continue* to receive downvotes after your edit, I rather suspect that the answer is yes. It's still not particularly clear what you're asking, nor why you accepted the answer that you did and you've also attracted attention to it (via this meta question), which means that there's going to be a [Streisand Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect) happening.</s>

The question is now deleted. I think this is probably for the best, for the reasons detailed above.

Comment: The question that keeps getting downvotes has already been closed. It was assumed to be needing details or clarity.

Comment: Also, I think the users who downvoted my question wasn't the ones who upvoted the comment, because the upvotes were older than the question downvotes.